# Issue formatting dollar amount in input

Tags: angularjs, input, number-formatting

I have a created Angular directive for formatting dollar amounts for an input box when a user enters in a dollar amount. Ideally the amount will always format to 2 decimal places on blur. For example, 3 would return 3.00, 1.1 would return 1.10 and so on. However when I enter an amount such as 1.01 it returns 1.010 which is not ideal as it adds the extra decimal place. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Here's the code for the directive

```
'use strict';

angular.module('edAssistApp').directive('format', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
            var formatType = $attrs.format.split(':')[0];
            var formatParam = $attrs.format.split(':')[1];

            if (!$ctrl) {
                return;
            }

            $ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function (a) {
                return $filter($attrs.format)($ctrl.$modelValue);
            });

            // This will parse the value that was put in and format to a currency number
            // (i.e., 1234.56). First it determines if the number is valid (isNaN),
            // then it will truncate the number down to 2 decimal points (... * 100 / 100),
            // then it will convert it to a string and split by the '.' (if there is one),
            // if the decimal is < 10, add a 0 so it will always have 2 digits.
            $elem.bind('blur', function(event) {
                var outputVal = '';

                if (!isNaN(parseFloat($elem.val()))) {
                    var parsedNumber = Math.round(parseFloat($elem.val()) * 100) / 100;
                    var p2dec = parsedNumber.toString().split('.')[1] || 0;
                    if (p2dec < 10) {
                        p2dec += '0';
                    }

                    outputVal = [parsedNumber.toString().split('.')[0], p2dec].join('.');
                }

                $elem.val($filter(formatType, formatParam)(outputVal));
                $ctrl.$setViewValue(outputVal);
                $ctrl.$render();

            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the toFixed function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) which will do all the math for you.

```
let a = 1.1;
console.log(a.toFixed(2)); // will output 1.10
```